# PHP another HTML code after click a Button

Tags: php, html, button

i have following code:

```
  <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="ok" value="ÓK">
  </form>
  <?php
    if (isset($_POST['ok'])) 
    { 
      printf "OK";
    }  
  ?>
```

I want that there would be another html code that appear after the button is pressed

i have no idea how to do it

Comment: I - [as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484421/how-get-unix-timestamp-from-given-date-and-time-in-php#comment27172474_18484421) - strongly recommend to [thoroughly read our Ask Advice again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) (including all the links given in there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="ok" value="ÓK">
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['ok'])) 
    { 
?>

<div>
<p>Your HTML-code here</p>
</div>

<?php
    }  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the header() method for redirecting. If you want to echo simple html just do it:

```
echo("<div></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you now have printf "ok";
put

```
?> <?php
```

And between it you can put your new HTML

Answer (score 0):

use **print** or **echo** , not **printf**

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for another chunk of HTML code to appear when the button is clicked then you will need to have a JavaScript function which is called when an `onclick` event occurs on the button.

I'm not great with JS so I leave this as an exercise for the OP

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the form with [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp). In pure javascript you can use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object.

Here is example of simple `ajax.php` file:

```html
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ok'])) {
    // send some response here
    var_export($_POST);
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajax() {
    var form = document.forms['form1'];
    var queryString = 'test=' + form['test'].value + '&ok=' + form['ok'].value;
    var xmlHttpReq = false;
    var self = this;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla/Chrome/Opera/Safari/IE9+
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE6-8
        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', 'ajax.php', true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = self.xmlHttpReq.responseText;
        }
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.send(queryString); // send http request
    return false; // disable submitting the form below and thus reloading the page
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return ajax();">
    <input type="text" name="test" value="test data" />
    <input type="submit" name="ok" value="OK" />
</form>
<div id="result" style="background:#faa;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```